# Get proper docstring like in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, docstring

In Jupyter notebooks you get the full docstring of symbols by shfit-tabbing:

[image]

Pycharm's ctrl-Q behavior is abysmal in comparison and mostly useless. Poorly formatted lacking crucial pieces of documentation like the parameter descriptions:

[image]

Is there a way to get Pycharm to display the docstring like in Jupyter?

Comment: control and click the method ....

Comment: @BhosaleShrikant Cool. Do you know if there is shortcut for this? nvm. It is ctrl+B

Comment: or set a caret on its usage and call `ctrl+q`

Comment: @user2235698 What do you mean "set a caret on its usage"?

Comment: @lo tolmencre let's consider expression `print("Hello")` as a usage of print function, then setting a caret on its usage means to put cursor to any part of `print` in `print("Hello")`